# Data synchronization between primary and redundant servers

Tags: rest, synchronization, apache-zookeeper, hazelcast, atomix

I want to synchronize data among a set of REST API servers(Spring Boot based API cluster) periodically. Any instance in the cluster should be able to broadcast new information to all others.

I don't want to use a DB here. I am trying to find a lightweight library that can be used inside the API for this purpose. Is it possible to use Atomoix/Hazelcast/ZooKeeper for this purpose? If so, it will be really helpful if someone can post a sample code - if possible.

My thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hazelcast can be used for this use-case. Each of the REST instances will create an embedded Hazelcast member within its JVM. Hazelcast members then discover each other and form the cluster. Your REST apps will use the IMap or ReplicatedMap service - a distributed key-value store (IMap can store more data, ReplicatedMap is faster). Once you write a data to the IMap all other instances see it right away.

See the code sample here: https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/latest/getting-started/get-started-java.html#complete-code-samples

This feature and the Spring integration are open-source.

Comment: Looks promising. Thank you very much. Will try it out. Right now, working on a POC with Atomix.

Comment: Awesome. It works. With Atomix, broadcasting worked but I couldn't replicate data. But this works like a charm. By the way, I used their Spring Boot sample provided: https://guides.hazelcast.org/hazelcast-embedded-springboot/#_what_youll_learn

Answer (score 1):

In Hazelcast you can do it through WAN replication.

It is an enterprise feature you have to buy a license.

Comment: Thanks but looking for an opensource solution.